# How to protect routes in core ui react

Tags: react-router, core-ui

I have downloaded react admin dashboard from core ui, now I need to protect the dashboard routes defined in it, so how can I do that,

routes.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Loadable from 'react-loadable'

import DefaultLayout from './containers/DefaultLayout';

function Loading() {
  return <div>Loading...</div>;
}

const Breadcrumbs = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('./views/Base/Breadcrumbs'),
  loading: Loading,
});

const Cards = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('./views/Base/Cards'),
  loading: Loading,
});

const Carousels = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('./views/Base/Carousels'),
  loading: Loading,
});

const Collapses = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('./views/Base/Collapses'),
  loading: Loading,
});

const Dropdowns = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('./views/Base/Dropdowns'),
  loading: Loading,
});

const Forms = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('./views/Base/Forms'),
  loading: Loading,
});

const Jumbotrons = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('./views/Base/Jumbotrons'),
  loading: Loading,
});

const ListGroups = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('./views/Base/ListGroups'),
  loading: Loading,
});

const Navbars = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('./views/Base/Navbars'),
  loading: Loading,
});

const Navs = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('./views/Base/Navs'),
  loading: Loading,
});

const Paginations = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('./views/Base/Paginations'),
  loading: Loading,
});

const Popovers = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('./views/Base/Popovers'),
  loading: Loading,
});

const ProgressBar = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('./views/Base/ProgressBar'),
  loading: Loading,
});

const Switches = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('./views/Base/Switches'),
  loading: Loading,
});

const Tables = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('./views/Base/Tables'),
  loading: Loading,
});

const Tabs = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('./views/Base/Tabs'),
  loading: Loading,
});

const Tooltips = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('./views/Base/Tooltips'),
  loading: Loading,
});

const BrandButtons = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('./views/Buttons/BrandButtons'),
  loading: Loading,
});

const ButtonDropdowns = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('./views/Buttons/ButtonDropdowns'),
  loading: Loading,
});

const ButtonGroups = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('./views/Buttons/ButtonGroups'),
  loading: Loading,
});

const Buttons = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('./views/Buttons/Buttons'),
  loading: Loading,
});

const Charts = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('./views/Charts'),
  loading: Loading,
});

const Dashboard = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('./views/Dashboard'),
  loading: Loading,
});

const CoreUIIcons = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('./views/Icons/CoreUIIcons'),
  loading: Loading,
});

const Flags = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('./views/Icons/Flags'),
  loading: Loading,
});

const FontAwesome = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('./views/Icons/FontAwesome'),
  loading: Loading,
});

const SimpleLineIcons = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('./views/Icons/SimpleLineIcons'),
  loading: Loading,
});

const Alerts = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('./views/Notifications/Alerts'),
  loading: Loading,
});

const Badges = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('./views/Notifications/Badges'),
  loading: Loading,
});

const Modals = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('./views/Notifications/Modals'),
  loading: Loading,
});

const Colors = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('./views/Theme/Colors'),
  loading: Loading,
});

const Typography = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('./views/Theme/Typography'),
  loading: Loading,
});

const Widgets = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('./views/Widgets/Widgets'),
  loading: Loading,
});


// https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-config
const routes = [
  { path: '/', exact: true, name: 'Home', component: DefaultLayout },
  { path: '/dashboard', name: 'Dashboard', component: Dashboard },
  { path: '/theme', exact: true, name: 'Theme', component: Colors },
  { path: '/theme/colors', name: 'Colors', component: Colors },
  { path: '/theme/typography', name: 'Typography', component: Typography },
  { path: '/base', exact: true, name: 'Base', component: Cards },
  { path: '/base/cards', name: 'Cards', component: Cards },
  { path: '/base/forms', name: 'Forms', component: Forms },
  { path: '/base/switches', name: 'Switches', component: Switches },
  { path: '/base/tables', name: 'Tables', component: Tables },
  { path: '/base/tabs', name: 'Tabs', component: Tabs },
  { path: '/base/breadcrumbs', name: 'Breadcrumbs', component: Breadcrumbs },
  { path: '/base/carousels', name: 'Carousel', component: Carousels },
  { path: '/base/collapses', name: 'Collapse', component: Collapses },
  { path: '/base/dropdowns', name: 'Dropdowns', component: Dropdowns },
  { path: '/base/jumbotrons', name: 'Jumbotrons', component: Jumbotrons },
  { path: '/base/list-groups', name: 'List Groups', component: ListGroups },
  { path: '/base/navbars', name: 'Navbars', component: Navbars },
  { path: '/base/navs', name: 'Navs', component: Navs },
  { path: '/base/paginations', name: 'Paginations', component: Paginations },
  { path: '/base/popovers', name: 'Popovers', component: Popovers },
  { path: '/base/progress-bar', name: 'Progress Bar', component: ProgressBar },
  { path: '/base/tooltips', name: 'Tooltips', component: Tooltips },
  { path: '/buttons', exact: true, name: 'Buttons', component: Buttons },
  { path: '/buttons/buttons', name: 'Buttons', component: Buttons },
  { path: '/buttons/button-dropdowns', name: 'Button Dropdowns', component: ButtonDropdowns },
  { path: '/buttons/button-groups', name: 'Button Groups', component: ButtonGroups },
  { path: '/buttons/brand-buttons', name: 'Brand Buttons', component: BrandButtons },
  { path: '/icons', exact: true, name: 'Icons', component: CoreUIIcons },
  { path: '/icons/coreui-icons', name: 'CoreUI Icons', component: CoreUIIcons },
  { path: '/icons/flags', name: 'Flags', component: Flags },
  { path: '/icons/font-awesome', name: 'Font Awesome', component: FontAwesome },
  { path: '/icons/simple-line-icons', name: 'Simple Line Icons', component: SimpleLineIcons },
  { path: '/notifications', exact: true, name: 'Notifications', component: Alerts },
  { path: '/notifications/alerts', name: 'Alerts', component: Alerts },
  { path: '/notifications/badges', name: 'Badges', component: Badges },
  { path: '/notifications/modals', name: 'Modals', component: Modals },
  { path: '/widgets', name: 'Widgets', component: Widgets },
  { path: '/charts', name: 'Charts', component: Charts },
];

export default routes;
```

Here is the source for [core ui react admin dashboard](https://github.com/coreui/coreui-free-react-admin-template)

I know protecting routes defined in App.js ,but here they routes are placed in constant, can anyone please tell me how to protect routes if and only if token is there then routing should happen otherwise don't.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You probably have already solved this. But in case you are still stuck, you can define the protecting routes in App.js or DefaultLayout inside container folder.

Assuming that you are storing tokens in localstorage/ cookie, use the following code in DefaultLayout inside Switch block:

```
{routes.map((route, idx) => {
  return route.component ? (
    <Route
      key={idx}
      path={route.path}
      exact={route.exact}
      name={route.name}
      render={props =>
        get_token_from_storage_or_cookie("tokenName") !== null
       ? (
          <route.component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect to={{ pathname: "/login" }} />
        )
      }
    />
  ) : null;
})}
<Redirect from="/" to="/dashboard" />
```

Comment: yeah i solved it using same approach, thanks anyway :)-

Comment: saved my life in 2021.

Comment: I need to do the same for Berry react template.. someone assist

Comment: index.tsx:24 Uncaught Error: [Navigate] is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>    got this error

Answer (score 4):

In react route v6 and core UI 4 work for me:

```
<Route
  key={idx}
  path={route.path}
  exact={route.exact}
  name={route.name}
  element={
    localStorage.getItem("loginUser") !== null ? (
      <route.element />
    ) : (
      <Navigate to="/login" />
    )
  }
/>
```

Comment: I used above code in AppContent.js file and it works for me. thank you.